# Is this sand or motar?

Tags: brick, mortar

Originally I was going to repair the joints on my 20 yo brick stairs (pic A)

[image]

As I was chipping away the broken joints I noticed a few of the joints had the consistency of wet beach sand and I could scoop them out with my finger (pic B)

[image]

These wet joints lead me to lift out a few bricks.  There is this wet sand below (pic C)

[image]

Was this wet sand intended to be there to set the bricks or a bad handyman job?

Comment: Ground up gravel. Looks like *fines* on top of *3/4" minus*. That's everything that should be there except the 1" of sand (which is optional if you can get a good lay on fines). https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/49476/23295

Comment: Is this a flat area or stairs going up?

Comment: @Polypipe Wrangler  This is a prefabbed two stair staircase with inlaid bricks.  The photo is of the bricks on the top landing in front of the entry door.